# Navigating google search pages using next button and printing link titles by WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to print all the titles of search results page by page.

Searching google and then printing titles of first page results is successful. But when I try to click next button and then print the titles of second page results, I am getting `StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache` error.

How do I print the second page titles after clicking next button on first page.

My code:

```
public class goopick {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    searchGoogle(driver, "Selenium Interview Questions");       

    printSiteNames(getSiteNames(driver));       

    clickNextButton(driver);

    printSiteNames(getSiteNames(driver));       

}

private static List<WebElement> getSiteNames(WebDriver driver){
    return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div[@class='rc']/h3/a"));
}

private static void searchGoogle(WebDriver driver, String searchString) {
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=LSX1VvXDLKmumQW7irJw&gws_rd=ssl");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(searchString);
    driver.findElement(By.className("lsb")).click();
}

private static void printSiteNames(List<WebElement> sitenames) {
    int i = 1;
    System.out.println("----------------------------------xxxx----------------------------");
    for (WebElement sitename : sitenames) {
        String site = sitename.getText();
        System.out.println(i + ") " + site);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------xxxx----------------------------");
}

private static void clickNextButton(WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement NextButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/span[2]"));
    NextButton.click();
    System.out.println("Next Button Clicked");
    driver.navigate().forward();
  }
}
```

Output and error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 30.79 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
```

Comment: debugging will help you out.!!

Comment: Beware that the Next page button starts an XHR request - meaning that Selenium will not wait the request to finish, it will simply continue the execution. After you press the button you get the elements from the 1st page most probably (as the update is not immediate). When you try to get the titles however the page is already updated with the new results, and the first page's titles are not present anymore. Wait until the 2nd page loads before continuing.

Comment: Do some wait after click on the Next Button.

Answer (score 0):

@praveen kumar - You can update your code once you reach on your next page. Identify xpath for the text you want to print and update your xpath/class id/ link id in the below code and it will work for you:

```
@Test(priority=2)
        public void printPageHeader() throws InterruptedException{

            java.util.List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/header/nav[1]/div/div/span/span"));
            for ( WebElement element: allText) { 
                System.out.println(element.getText());
        }  
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

@ Praveen Kumar first please understand what is stale element exception.A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases,

```
1.The element has been deleted entirely.(more common)
2.The element is no longer attached to the DOM.
```

for more info please go to selenium official website `http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp`

Now solving your problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=OhT5VrLwE-iK8QfV74WwCA");

        // performing google search
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium Interview Questions");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

        // printing all sites name 

        List<WebElement> allsites = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div[@class='rc']/h3/a"));
        for(int i =0;i<allsites.size();i++){
            System.out.println("All Sites Name is : " + allsites.get(i).getText());
            // now clicking link to go to the next page 
            allsites.get(i).click();

            // getting title of the opened URL
            System.out.println("Title of the Next Page is : "+ driver.getTitle());

            // navigating back to the previous page 
            driver.navigate().back();

            // now when you will try to click the next link in the line you will face 
            // Stale Element Exception as element is not attached to the page document
            // so re-attached it we have to redefine it.
            allsites = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div[@class='rc']/h3/a"));

            // now it will work like a charm. Hope this solves the issue
        }

    }
```

Hope this solves your problem.